# what is the encoding of upload .ogg file to mongodb with python?

Tags: mongodb, encoding, utf-8, gridfs, python-3.6

i am writing a script for upload a .ogg file to mongodb through the python.
i am using python 3.6 and just studying recently, so I haven't any ideas. please help me.

### this is my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
import os`

db=MongoClient().FypDatabase
fs=gridfs.GridFS(db,collection='video')
fs.put(open('C:\\testStream5.ogg','UTF-8'))`
```

---

but it say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\chingyi\Desktop\testUp.py", line 16, in <module>
        fs.put(open('C:\\testStream5.ogg','UTF-8'))
            ValueError: invalid mode: 'UTF-8'`
```

---

I had do some research. I knew i must write the encoding inside like:
[Streaming file data into mongodb gridfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270876/streaming-file-data-into-mongodb-gridfs)
so i write fs.put(fileName,'UTF-8')
also, i read this page: 
[encoding](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.0rc1/api/gridfs/grid_file.html)
it say [
"encoding": encoding used for this file. In Python 2, any unicode that is written to the file will be converted to a str. In Python 3, any str that is written to the file will be converted to bytes.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OGG Vorbis files are binary files - **they do not have a text character encoding.**

You only need to supply the encoding argument to GridFs if your data is a `str`. Similarly, you only need to pass an encoding to `open()` if the file is text and is not in the default encoding for your platform.

In your case, as you're dealing with a binary file, you need to set the file mode to binary, which negates the encoding argument. Binary read-only file mode is given as `rb`.

Therefore, you simply need to do:

```
fs.put(open('C:\\testStream5.ogg', mode='rb'))
```

Comment: thank you your help and it can upload successfully. however, I cannot find the filename attribute and content-type attribute in my mongodb fs.files . is it auto write filename and content-type where I fs.put(filePath) ?

Comment: pass `filename` as an additional argument to `put`.